# Postgres Syntax to DJANGO ORM Syntax

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have the following Postgres syntax, that does what I want it to do, however, I would like to implement it in the models.py tab in ORM.

```
SELECT split_part(booking_inform, ',', 1) AS col1
     , split_part(booking_inform, ',', 2) AS col2
     , split_part(booking_inform, ',', 3) AS col3
     , split_part(booking_inform, ',', 4) AS col4
     , split_part(booking_inform, ',', 5) as col5
     , split_part(booking_inform, ',', 6) as col6

FROM   main_inmate;
```

I am splitting the column "booking inform" into six new columns based on a commas.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not store it in six different columns? It will make it harder to update/filter/... if you store it in e column.

Comment: as Willem already stated it would be better to split it in columns, if you still dont want to do it check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your Postgresql query would translate in Django ORM. Assuming your model is named `MainInmate`.

```py
from django.db.models import Func

class SplitPart(Func):
    function = 'split_part'
    arity = 3

MainInmate.objects.annotate(
   **{f'col{i}': SplitPart(F('booking_inform'), ',', i) for i in range(1, 7)}
).values(*[f'col{i}' for i in range(1, 7)])
```

However, if you store a list of values in a column, I would rather recommend to use a column of [array type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), which is available as [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) in Django.

Comment: Hi Antoine, if I have to also do an average on each of the column post split, what do I need to do additionally? It would be great if you could answer this.